# How to get FragmentDialog button response to adapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, adapter, android-alertdialog

I need to get the response of the pressed button from a FragmentDialog to an adapter.So basically i've set a click listener for a button in the viewholder and now when i press that button the dialog opens and i need to get the response of the two buttons that i set from that dialog.

My FragmentDialog:

```
public class FragmentDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment{
private EditText edtTextAmount;
private TextView txtEnterAmount;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_amount,null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            }).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    edtTextAmount=view.findViewById(R.id.edtTtxt_enterAmount);
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

My Adaptor:

```
public class WatchlistAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WatchlistAdaptor.WatchlistViewHolder>  {
//DescriptionFragment descriptionFragment;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<WatchlistItems> watchlistItems;
private Context context;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onDeleteClickRV(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

class WatchlistViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView cryptoImg;
    private TextView cryptoAcronym;
    private TextView cryptoName;
    private Button btnAddToActCurrencies;

    WatchlistViewHolder(View itemView/*, WatchlistAdaptor adaptor*/, final OnItemClickListener listener) {

        super(itemView);
        this.cryptoImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_wallet_WatchlistRV_cryptoImage);
        this.cryptoAcronym = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_wallet_WatchlistRV_cryptoAcronym);
        this.cryptoName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_wallet_WatchlistRV_cryptoName);
        this.btnAddToActCurrencies = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_wallet_WatchlistRV_AddToActCurrencies);
        // this.animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.anim_alpha);
        btnAddToActCurrencies.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) (context);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentDialog fragmentDialog = new FragmentDialog();
                fragmentDialog.show(fragmentManager, "fragmentalert");
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

...
    }

Comment: Create a custom event using `interface`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Review: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating
2. Add a listener to your fragment that is invoked when the button is clicked.

Example:

```
public class FragmentDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment{
private EditText edtTextAmount;
private TextView txtEnterAmount;

// Add listener class and instance
private OnButtonClickListener mListener;
interface OnButtonClickListener() {
    void onButtonClick();
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_amount,null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            }).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // Invoke listener on UI click
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onButtonClick();
            }
        }
    });
    edtTextAmount=view.findViewById(R.id.edtTtxt_enterAmount);
    return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        // Save context the fragment is attached to as the listener
        if (context instanceof OnButtonClickListener) {
            mListener = (OnButtonClickListener) context;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Update your activity to implement the interface and delegate the action

Example:

```
public void MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDialog.OnButtonClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onButtonClick() {
        // Since the activity implements the interface, it will be
        // called when the fragment button is clicked -
        // tell your adapter or whatever what to do
        mAdapter.handleButtonClick();
    }

}
```

Hope that helps!